# How to find in ElasticSearch for values which matches the string?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have stored values for example:

1. "ABC,DEF"
2. "ABC,34,DEF"
3. "ABC,DEF,FGH"
4. "ABC-FGH-DEF"
5. ",,ABC-DEF"

I need to query for values which matches the string "ABCDEF" after removing all not chars.

So in response I need to have only records 1,2,5

Answer (score 1):

If the query value has a space between `ABC` and `DEF`, then you can use the normal `query` but **without** using `.keyword` after the field name.

for example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "textField": "ABC DEF"
    }
  }
}
```